# Memory allocation error in copy construtor (c++)

Tags: c++, memory, constructor, matrix, numeric

I've got a problem.

I've already wrote quite a piece of code in C++. I'm using MS Visual Studio 2010.

It's a class `matrix` with few simple numerical functions.

Below are implementations:

```
//matrix.h
#pragma once
#define EPS pow(10., -12.)

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

class matrix
{
private:
    unsigned int n;     //number of columns
    unsigned int m;     //number of rows
    double* T;
public: 
    matrix ();
    matrix (unsigned int _n);
    matrix (unsigned int _n, unsigned int _m);
    ~matrix ();
    matrix (const matrix& A);
    matrix operator = (const matrix& A);

    unsigned int size_n () const;
    unsigned int size_m () const;

    void ones ();
    void zeros ();
    void identity ();

    void push (unsigned int i, unsigned int j, double v);

    void lu ();
    void gauss ();
    double det ();
    void transposition ();
    void inverse ();
    bool symmetric ();
    bool diag_strong_domination ();

    void swap_rows (unsigned int i, unsigned int j);

    matrix gauss_eq (matrix b);

    friend bool operator == (const matrix A, const matrix B);

    friend matrix operator + (const matrix A, const matrix B);

    friend matrix operator * (const matrix A, const matrix B);

    double operator () (unsigned int i, unsigned int j) const;

    friend ostream& operator << (ostream& out, const matrix& A);
};

matrix::matrix () : n(0), m(0)
{    
    this->T = NULL;
}


matrix::matrix (unsigned int _n) : n(_n), m(_n)
{    
    if (0==_n)
    {
        this->T = NULL;
        return;
    }

    this->T = new double [(this->n)*(this->m)];

    for (unsigned int i=0; i<this->n*this->m; i++)
        this->T[i] = (double)0;
}


matrix::matrix (unsigned int _n, unsigned int _m) : n(_n), m(_m)
{
    if (0==_m || 0==_n)
        throw "Error: Wrong matrix dimensios";

    this->T = new double [n*m];

    for (unsigned int i=0; i<n*m; i++)
        this->T[i] = (double)0;
}


matrix::~matrix ()
{
    delete this->T;
}


matrix::matrix (const matrix& A) : n(A.n), m(A.m)
{
    this->T = new double [n*m]; //(double*)malloc(A.m*A.n*sizeof(double));

    for (unsigned int i=0; i<n*m; i++)
        this->T[i] = A.T[i];
}


matrix matrix::operator= (const matrix& A)
{
    if (!(*this==A))
    {
        this->m = A.m;
        this->n = A.n;

        delete this->T;
        this->T = new double [A.n*A.m];

        for (unsigned int i=0; i<A.n*A.m; i++)
            this->T[i] = A.T[i];
    }

    return *this;
}



unsigned int matrix::size_n () const
{
    return this->n;
}

unsigned int matrix::size_m () const
{
    return this->m;
}

void matrix::ones ()
{
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<(this->m)*(this->m); i++)
        (*this).T[i] = double(1);

    return;
}

void matrix::zeros ()
{
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<(this->m)*(this->m); i++)
        (*this).T[i] = double(0);

    return;
}

void matrix::identity ()
{
    if (this->m!=this->n)
        throw "Error: Matrix have to be square (identity)";

    for (unsigned int i=0; i<(this->m)*(this->m); i++)
        (*this).T[i] = double(0);

    for (unsigned int k=1; k<=this->m; k++)
        (*this).push(k, k, (double)1);

    return;

}

void matrix::push (unsigned int i, unsigned int j, double v)
{
    if (i<=0 || i>this->m || j<=0 || j>this->n)
        throw "Error: Indeks out of range (push)";

    this->T[(i-1)*this->n + (j-1)] = v;
}


void matrix::lu ()
{
    if (this->m!=this->n)
        throw "Error: Matrix have to be square (lu)";

    if ((*this).diag_strong_domination())
    {
        //Doolittle decomposition
        matrix L(this->m);
        matrix U(this->m);

        for (unsigned int b=1; b<=this->m; b++)
            L.push(b, b, (double)1);

        for (unsigned int b=1; b<=this->m; b++)
            U.push(1, b, (*this)(1,b));

        for (unsigned int b=2; b<=this->m; b++)
        {
            for (unsigned int c=1; c<=this->m; c++)
            {
                for (unsigned int k=1; k<=b-1; k++)
                {
                    double s1 = 0;

                    if (1==k)
                        s1 = (double)0;

                    else
                        for (unsigned int p=1; p<=k-1; p++)
                            s1 += L(b,p) * U(p,k);

                    double v = ((*this)(b,k) - s1)/U(k,k);
                    L.push(b, k, v);
                }
                for (unsigned int k=b; k<=this->m; k++)
                {
                    double s2 = 0;

                    for (unsigned int p=1; p<=b-1; p++)
                        s2 += L(b,p) * U(p,k);

                    double v = (*this)(b,k) - s2;
                    U.push(b, k, v);
                }
            }
        }

        for (unsigned int p=1; p<=this->m; p++)
            L.push(p, p, (double)0);

        (*this) = L + U;

        for (unsigned int x=0; x<(*this).m*(*this).n; x++)
        {
            if (abs((*this).T[x])<EPS)
                (*this).T[x] = (double)0;
        }

        return;
    }

    (*this).gauss();

    return;
}


void matrix::gauss()
{
    //LU decomposition (gauss elimination with partal choice of main element)
    unsigned int n = (*this).m;
    matrix U(*this);
    matrix svr(1,n);
    for (unsigned int a=1; a<=n; a++)
        svr.push(a, 1, a);

    for (unsigned int k = 1; k<=(n-1); k++)
    {
        //main element choice - column
        unsigned int max = k;
        for (unsigned int q=k; q<=n; q++)
        {
            if (abs(U(q,k)) > abs(U(max,k)))
                max = q;
        }
        unsigned int p = max;
        svr.push(k, 1, p);


        if (abs(U(p,k)) < EPS)
            throw "Error: det = 0";

        //main element swap
        if (p!=k)
            U.swap_rows(p, k);

        //elimination
        for (unsigned int i=(k+1); i<=n; i++)
        {
            double tmp = U(i,k)/U(k,k);
            for (unsigned int j=(k+1); j<=n; j++)
            {
                double v = U(i,j) - tmp * U(k,j);
                U.push(i, j, v);
            }
        }
    }

    if (abs(U(n,n)) < EPS)
        throw "Error: det = 0";

    for (unsigned int s=2; s<=n; s++)
        for (unsigned int t=1; t<=(s-1); t++)
            U.push(s, t, (double)0);

    matrix T = (*this);
    matrix Uinv(U);
    Uinv.inverse();
    matrix L(n);

    for (unsigned int i=1; i<=n; i++)
        for (unsigned int j=1; j<=n; j++)
            for (unsigned int k=1; k<=n; k++)
            {
                double v = T(i,k) * Uinv(k,j);
                L.push(i, j, v);
            }

    //reversing rows swap
    for (unsigned int t=1; t<=n; t++)
    {
        if (t!=svr(t,1))
            L.swap_rows(t, svr(t,1));
    }

    (*this) = L + U;

    for (unsigned int k=1; k<=n; k++)
        (*this).push(k, k, (*this)(k,k) - (double)1);

    for (unsigned int x=0; x<(*this).m*(*this).n; x++)
    {
        if (abs((*this).T[x])<EPS)
            (*this).T[x] = (double)0;
    }

    return;
}


double matrix::det ()
{
    if (this->m!=this->n)
        throw "Error: Matrix have to be square (det)";

    double det = 1;
    matrix TMP = (*this);
TMP.lu();

for (unsigned int i=1; i<=this->m; i++)
        det *= (double)(TMP(i,i));

return det;
}


void matrix::transposition()
{
    matrix R(*this);

    for (unsigned int i=1; i<=(*this).m; i++)
        for (unsigned int j=1; j<=(*this).n; j++)
            (*this).push(j, i, R(i,j));

    return;
}


void matrix::inverse ()
{
    unsigned int n = (*this).m;

    matrix A(*this);
    matrix X(n);
    matrix b(1,n);

    for (unsigned int i=1; i<=n; i++)
    {
        b.zeros();
        b.push(i, 1, (double)1);

        X = A.gauss_eq(b); //error when using inverse in gauss function, used in lu

        for (unsigned int k=1; k<=n; k++)
            (*this).push(i, k, X(k,1));
        }

    for (unsigned int x=0; x<(*this).m*(*this).n; x++)
        if (abs((*this).T[x])<EPS)
            (*this).T[x] = (double)0;

    return; //error when calling inverse
}


bool matrix::diag_strong_domination()
{
    for (unsigned int i=1; i<=n; i++)
    {
        double s = (double)0;

        for (unsigned int j=1; j<=n; j++)
        {
            if (j!=i)
                s += abs((*this)(i,j));
        }

        if (s>=abs((*this)(i,i)))
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}


void matrix::swap_rows (unsigned int i, unsigned int j)
{
    if (i<=0 || i>this->m || j<=0 || j>this->n)
        throw "Error: Indeks out of range (swap_rows)";

    matrix R(*this);

    for (unsigned int p=1; p<=this->m; p++)
        for (unsigned int q=1; q<=this->n; q++)
        {
            if (p==i)
                (*this).push(p, q, R(j,q));
            if (p==j)
                (*this).push(p, q, R(i,q));
        }

    return;
}


matrix matrix::gauss_eq (matrix b)
{
    matrix A(*this);
    unsigned int n = this->m;

    for (unsigned int k=1; k<=n-1; k++)
    {
        unsigned int max = k;
        for (unsigned int q=k; q<=n; q++)
        {
            if (abs(A(q,k)) > abs(A(max,k)))
                max = q;
        }
        unsigned int p = max;

        if (abs(A(p,k)) < EPS)
            throw "Error: det = 0 (gauss_eq)";

        if (p!=k)
        {
            A.swap_rows(p,k);
            b.swap_rows(p,k);
        }

        for (unsigned int i=k+1; i<=n; i++)
        {
            double tmp = A(i,k) / A(k,k);
            for (unsigned int j=k+1; j<=n; j++)
                A.push(i, j, A(i,j) - tmp*A(k,j));
            b.push(i, 1, b(i,1) - tmp*b(k,1));
        }

        if (abs(A(n,n)) < EPS)
            throw "Error: det = 0 (gauss_eq)";
    }

    matrix X(1,n);

    double s = 0;

    for (unsigned int i=n; i>=1; i--)
    {
        for (unsigned int j=i+1; j<=n; j++)
            s = s + (A(i,j)*X(j,1));
        X.push(i, 1, (b(i,1)-s)/A(i,i));
        s = 0;
    }

    return X;
}


bool operator == (const matrix A, const matrix B)
{
    if (A.size_m()!=B.size_m() || A.size_n()!=B.size_n())
        return false;

    for (unsigned int i=1; i<=A.size_m(); i++)
        for (unsigned int j=1; j<=A.size_n(); j++)
            if (A(i,j)!=B(i,j))
                return false;

    return true;
}

matrix operator + (const matrix A, const matrix B)
{
    if (A.m!=B.m || A.n!=B.n)
        throw "Error: Wrong dimensions";

    matrix R(A.n, A.m);

    for (unsigned int i=0; i<A.m*A.n; i++)
        R.T[i] = A.T[i] + B.T[i];

    return R;
}

matrix operator * (const matrix A, const matrix B)
{
    if (A.n!=B.m)
        throw "Error: Wrong dimensions";

    matrix R(A.m,B.n);

    for (unsigned int i=1; i<=R.m; i++)
        for (unsigned int j=1; j<=R.n; j++)
            for (unsigned int k=1; k<=A.n; k++)
            {
                double v = R(i,j) + A(i,k) * B(k,j);
                R.push(i, j, v);
            }

    return R;
}

double matrix::operator () (unsigned int i, unsigned int j) const
{
    if (i<=0 || i>this->m || j<=0 || j>this->n)
        throw "Error: Indeks out of range (operator)";

    return this->T[(i-1)*this->n + (j-1)];
}

ostream& operator << (ostream& out, const matrix& A)
{
    if (0==A.size_m() || 0==A.size_n())
    {
        out<<endl<<" [  ]"<<endl;
        return out;
    }

    int s = 10;

    out<<endl<<" [ ";

    for (unsigned int i=1; i<=A.size_m(); i++)
    {
        for (unsigned int j=1; j<=A.size_n(); j++)
            out<<" "<<setw(s)<<left<<A(i,j)<<" ";

        if (i!=A.size_m())
            out<<endl<<"   ";
    }

    out<<" ] "<<endl;

    return out;
}
```

And the problem is that i have strange errors concerning memory.

Firstly, when I call function `inverse` like that:

```
//MatLab.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <complex>
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;

#include "matrix.h"

int main()
{
    try
    {
        matrix S(4);

        for (unsigned int i=1; i<=S.size_m(); i++)
            for (unsigned int j=1; j<=S.size_n(); j++)
            S.push(i, j, (double)3);

        for (unsigned int i=1; i<=S.size_m(); i++)
            S.push(i, i, (double)0);

        cout<<"S:"<<S<<endl;

        S.inverse();                     //<--- here is the problem
        cout<<endl<<"S^(-1) = "<<S<<endl;
    }
    catch (char* xcp)
    {
        cout<<endl<<xcp<<endl<<endl;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I got error when returning value in function `inverse`. When I step into I go to destrutor and have an error while I free memory.

However it's not all.

Another strange situation occurs when I call function `lu` like this:

```
//MatLab.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <complex>
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;

#include "matrix.h"

int main()
{
    try
    {
        matrix S(4);

        for (unsigned int i=1; i<=S.size_m(); i++)
            for (unsigned int j=1; j<=S.size_n(); j++)
            S.push(i, j, (double)3);

        for (unsigned int i=1; i<=S.size_m(); i++)
            S.push(i, i, (double)0);

        cout<<"S:"<<S<<endl;

        S.lu();                                  //<--- here is the problem
        cout<<endl<<"LU decomposition"<<S<<endl;
    }
    catch (char* xcp)
    {
        cout<<endl<<xcp<<endl<<endl;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

In this case error occurs also in function `inverse` used in function `gauss`, but this time when assigning the result of function `gauss_eq` to earlier defined matrix.

When I step into that problem I go to copy construtor (I don't know why) and I cannot allocate memory neither with new operator nor with `malloc` function.

When debugging nex statement to be executed is in `malloc.c` file in this function:

```
__forceinline void * __cdecl _heap_alloc (size_t size)

{

    if (_crtheap == 0) {
        _FF_MSGBANNER();    /* write run-time error banner */
        _NMSG_WRITE(_RT_CRT_NOTINIT);  /* write message */
        __crtExitProcess(255);  /* normally _exit(255) */
    }

    return HeapAlloc(_crtheap, 0, size ? size : 1);
}
```

And parameter size equals 68.

I have no idea what can be wrong.

Whether the problem is in constructors or functions in class matrix or maybe in function from C libraries I use.

I hope someone devote his time to look into this problem despite it's a lot of code to look over.

Thanks for any tips.

Comment: I bet most of your problems would go away if you swapped in `std::vector<double> T` in place of `double * T`.

Comment: Can you show us your implementations of the constructors and destructors, and possibly the implementation of the inverse function as well?  The pointer to double you are using is suspicious, but without seeing the code that uses it it's hard to tell if it's the problem or not.

Comment: For starters, your destructor, as well as assignment operator, has the wrong `delete` in it. Go with @BenjaminLindley's suggestion if you can.

Comment: All implementations are in the first code box.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't read all your code but this is definitely wrong:

```
matrix::~matrix ()
{
    delete this->T;
}
```

You need to be calling the `delete[]` operator, not plain `delete`.  `new` must always be matched with `delete`, and `new[]` must always be matched with `delete[]`.  Failure to do is is undefined behavior and will usually result in some sort of memory corruption that will crash your program.

Likewise your implementation of `operator =` should also call `delete[]`.

There's also no need to prefix every member access with `this->` or `(*this).`.  It's not idiomatic C++ and should only be used in cases where there's a local variable shadowing a member variable (which itself isn't always good practice).

Comment: I think, that when I use ie. `n` it means `this->n` or `(*this).n`.

Answer (score 2):

First, way, *way* too much code.  However, the problem is simple; you call `delete` on the array that you allocated with `new []`.  Anything allocated with `new[]` must be deallocated with `delete[]`.  You have the same problem in `operator=`.

Comment: It turned out not to be so simple.

Comment: @kostek: Well the delete call is still wrong and you were invoking undefined behavior. As I said, you posted a lot of code.  The more code there is the less likely someone is to debug through it.  Glad you have it solved now though.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use an appropriate managing class, not doing it yourself. Since you already do your own 2D indexing, a `std::vector<double>` would be a fine thing.

Comment: I don't wont to use stl containers, yet write something myself.

Comment: Then write your own `std::vector` replacement first, then base your Matrix class off that.

Answer (score 0):

Your assignment operator is wrong, where you wrote

```
matrix matrix::operator=(const matrix& A)
{
    if (!(*this==A))
```

you actually meant to write

```
matrix& matrix::operator=(const matrix& A)
{
    if (this != &A)
```

You should be checking in the addresses of the two objects are not equal, not if the matrices themselves are not equal (and also operator= should return a reference).

But in any case this style of assignment operator is bad. There's a better way of writing assignment operators called the copy and swap idiom. It's not only more correct it's also easier to write. See here for an example

http://programmingexamples.net/wiki/CPP/C%2B%2B0x/TheBigFive

Comment: Having thought about, saying your assignment operator is wrong is in fact wrong. It's unusual, it could be improved, but it's not incorrect.

Comment: I didn't want to check if `this` points to the same address as `A` does, but if `(*this)` equals `A`.

Comment: Yes, I realise that now. It's unusual, but it's not wrong. If you look at the link I posted it does describe a better way to write the assignment operator.

Comment: I looked at the idea of copy and swap and for me it's very nice and simple so I accepted your answer, however it didn't solve my problem at all.

Comment: Nice of you to accept my answer, not so nice to take it away again. Oh well, I'm sure you made the right decision.

Answer (score 0):

OK. I've made some changes and now I free memory like that:

```
matrix::~matrix ()
{
    delete [] this->T;
}
```

and

```
matrix& matrix::operator= (const matrix& A)
{
    if (!(*this==A))
    {
        this->m = A.m;
        this->n = A.n;

        delete [] this->T;
        this->T = new double [A.n*A.m];

        for (unsigned int i=0; i<A.n*A.m; i++)
            this->T[i] = A.T[i];
    }

    return *this;
}
```

But it changed anything in both calling `inverse` itself as well in `gauss`.

While debugging I stopped at

```
extern "C" _CRTIMP int __cdecl _CrtIsValidHeapPointer(
        const void * pUserData
        )
{
        if (!pUserData)
            return FALSE;

        if (!_CrtIsValidPointer(pHdr(pUserData), sizeof(_CrtMemBlockHeader), FALSE))
            return FALSE;

        return HeapValidate( _crtheap, 0, pHdr(pUserData) );  /<-- here I stopped
}
```

in `dbgheap.c`.

Comment: However I thought that with `delete []` I free static tables like `double T [100]`. And the table that I use is dynamic so it ought to be freed with `delete`.